# FreeNAS AFP Doesn't Authenticate

Tags: mac-osx, truenas, afp, netatalk

I just set up a FreeNAS 8.0.3 server and am trying to use its AFP (Netatalk) service to access it via a Mac OS X Lion system. I created the ZFS volume, set its permissions to include my user in its owner group (and set group write permissions), created an AFP share with AFP3 and told that share to "allow" @uninet (my group). I have a user on the server named tbutler, matching the user on my Mac.

I can see the server, "Beatrice," in Finder. When I try to login in Finder using "Connect As...," the user "tbutler" and the proper password, I am returned to the main Finder window with the black bar now saying "Connection Failed."

Here's the most recent data from /var/messages on the server, which shows me trying to login both as a "Registered User" and a "Guest":

```
Jul 30 00:29:07 freenas afpd[8972]: AFP3.3 Login by nobody
Jul 30 00:29:08 freenas afpd[8972]: AFP logout by nobody
Jul 30 00:29:08 freenas afpd[8972]: dsi_stream_read: len:0, unexpected EOF
Jul 30 00:29:08 freenas afpd[8972]: afp_over_dsi: client logged out, terminating DSI session
Jul 30 00:29:08 freenas afpd[8972]: AFP statistics: 0.14 KB read, 0.12 KB written
Jul 30 00:29:14 freenas afpd[8975]: AFP3.3 Login by tbutler
Jul 30 00:29:14 freenas afpd[8975]: AFP logout by tbutler
Jul 30 00:29:14 freenas afpd[8975]: dsi_stream_read: len:0, unexpected EOF
Jul 30 00:29:14 freenas afpd[8975]: afp_over_dsi: client logged out, terminating DSI session
Jul 30 00:29:14 freenas afpd[8975]: AFP statistics: 0.62 KB read, 0.48 KB written
Jul 30 00:29:20 freenas afpd[8978]: AFP3.3 Login by tbutler
Jul 30 00:29:20 freenas afpd[8978]: AFP logout by tbutler
Jul 30 00:29:20 freenas afpd[8978]: dsi_stream_read: len:0, unexpected EOF
Jul 30 00:29:20 freenas afpd[8978]: afp_over_dsi: client logged out, terminating DSI session
Jul 30 00:29:20 freenas afpd[8978]: AFP statistics: 0.62 KB read, 0.48 KB written
Jul 30 00:29:27 freenas afpd[8983]: AFP3.3 Login by nobody
```

(My clock is clearly not properly set, but be that as it may...)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: Apparently this problem occurs if one gives the AFP share a password in the AFP share settings box. When I removed the password and tried to login using a user account again, it worked just fine.

Comment: No. And, it is still the cleanest option on OS X (especially with Time Machine).

Comment: This still seems to be true in 8.3.1.